# WaveMediaStreamSource not working on Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, wavmss

I downloaded the Silverlight `WaveMediaStreamSource` from this [site](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/wavmss).

but I am having issues playing .wav files on Windows phone 7 using this `wavemediastreamsource` with `MediaElement` control.

I need help from someone who has solved this problem to please share their code or help tell me changes they made to make it work.

I am able to successfully parse the .wav file and pull all header information.

I am stuck, any pointers and sample codes will help greatly if you have fixed this issue yourself or know how to.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quite understand your problem but you can take a look at the [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gillesk/archive/2009/03/23/playing-back-wave-files-in-silverlight.aspx).
It has nice little example about how to use `WaveMediaStreamSource` library.